# Error installing package (finalfit) in UBUNTU 20.4

Tags: r, linux, ubuntu

I get that error while installing package (finalfit) in ubuntu 20.4

```
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [/usr/share/R/share/make/shlib.mk:10: nloptr.so] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘nloptr’
* removing ‘/home/mohamed/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/nloptr’
ERROR: failed to lock directory ‘/home/mohamed/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1’ for modifying
Try removing ‘/home/mohamed/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/00LOCK-RcppEigen’
ERROR: dependencies ‘minqa’, ‘nloptr’, ‘RcppEigen’ are not available for package ‘lme4’
* removing ‘/home/mohamed/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/lme4’
ERROR: dependency ‘lme4’ is not available for package ‘finalfit’
* removing ‘/home/mohamed/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/finalfit’

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpKxavea/downloaded_packages’
Warning messages:
1: In install.packages("finalfit") :
  installation of package ‘minqa’ had non-zero exit status
2: In install.packages("finalfit") :
  installation of package ‘nloptr’ had non-zero exit status
3: In install.packages("finalfit") :
  installation of package ‘RcppEigen’ had non-zero exit status
4: In install.packages("finalfit") :
  installation of package ‘lme4’ had non-zero exit status
5: In install.packages("finalfit") :
  installation of package ‘finalfit’ had non-zero exit status
```

Can anyone help me?
I am Windows user and newbie in Ubuntu
I installed R version 4.1.2

Comment: you need to figure out why nloptr installation is failing. Probably you're missing some development libraries. Try to install that package directly and see the compilation errors.

Comment: Hi mohamed! Please provide information about your R session (`Sys.which("make")`; `sessionInfo()`). Try upgrade your system and install libnlopt-dev also: `sudo apt update`

`sudo apt-get install libnlopt-dev`

`sudo apt install build-essential`

`sudo apt upgrade`; Then in R try again: `install.packages("finalfit", dependencies = TRUE)`

Comment: when i tried sudo apt update I got this error E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/marutter/c2d4u/ubuntu focal Release' does not have a Release file.

Comment: @mohamed: I suggest you open another [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) about the PPA error message: it's probably non related to your R installation

Comment: @mohamed: Please provide information about your R session using `sessionInfo()` command in R. Try install the suggested packages in your system: `sudo apt-get install libnlopt-dev` `sudo apt-get install build-essential`. And then upgrade R packages, restart R and try again:  `install.packages("finalfit", dependencies = TRUE)`

Comment: I am sorry but the error is too long and I can't write it as a comment